# tictactoe with javascript using css3

Tags: javascript

I am using JavaScript to code the simple tictactoe game, but it displays (somebody won!!!) at the first click on the board, I know I am close but I cant find the problem in my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <style>
        .board{
            display: flex;
            width: 600px;
            height: 600px;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            justify-content: flex-start;
        }
       .square{
           width: 200px;
           height: 200px;
           box-sizing: border-box;
           border: 5px solid black;
           font-size: 5em;
           display: flex;
           justify-content: center;
           align-items: center;
       }
       .square:hover{
           cursor: pointer;
           background-color: #80cd92;
       }
   </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="board">
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
    <div class="square"> </div>
</div>

<script>
    var PLAYER_ONE_SYMBOL = 'X'
    var PLAYER_TWO_SYMBOL = 'O'
    var currentTurn = PLAYER_ONE_SYMBOL

    var board  = document.querySelector('.board')
    board.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
        e.target.innerHTML = currentTurn
        currentTurn = currentTurn === PLAYER_ONE_SYMBOL ? PLAYER_TWO_SYMBOL : PLAYER_ONE_SYMBOL
        if (checkForWinner())
        {alert(" somebody won !!! ")}
    })

    function checkForWinner(){
        var squares = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.square'), 0)
        var symbols = squares.map(function(square) {
            return square.innerHTML
        } )
        var winningCombos = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8],[0,3,6],[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[0,4,8],[2,4,6]]
          return winningCombos.find(function(combo)
          {
            if(symbols[combo[0]]==symbols[combo[1]]&&symbols[combo[1]]==symbols[combo[2]])
            {return symbols[combo[0]]}
            else {return false}

                 })
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial values for the squares are all the same (space), that's why the first evaluation will result in a winning combo. Field 0, 1 and 2 all have the same value.

You not only have to evaluate whether all three fields have the same value, but also whether or not they're equal to `X` or `O`.

Or you could do something like below, relying on the fact that the empty string is evaluated as *falsy*:

```
if(symbols[combo[0]] == symbols[combo[1]]
        && symbols[combo[1]] == symbols[combo[2]]) {

    return symbols[combo[0]].trim(); // will return 'X', 'O' or empty string
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Robby you solved the problem!!! i spent hours on this code trying to see what was wrong i happy you were able to help me, thanks again